# Logic Gate implementation fails

Tags: python, logic

I have made a logic gate that takes in two inputs which will then feed through into a AND gate in this case. For example the user will enter 0 and 0 then the AND gate will process as 0.

The problem here is when we use the IF statement to determine our two inputs, they are not recognised otherwise everything else in the program to process the two inputs along with a temporary storage for the output.

```
A = input("Enter a value of 1 or 0: ")
B = input("Enter a value of 1 or 0: ")
print(A)
print(B)
```

So the part above I am able to enter the inputs and create a storage for it.
The program tells me that A and B are unrecognised so does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

this is where the problem takes place: everything from here to the else statement is ignored.

```
def first_AND ():
if A == 0 and B == 0: 
    AND_1()
    print(AND)
    print("Now solve the XOR gate")
    gate_path_A()
elif A == 1 and B == 0:
    AND_2()
    print(AND)
    print("Now solve the XOR gate")
    gate_path_A()
elif A == 0 and B == 1:
    AND_3()
    print(AND)
    print("Now solve the XOR gate")
    gate_path_A()
elif A == 1 and B == 1:
    AND_4()
    print(AND)
    print("Now solve the XOR gate")
    gate_path_A()
else: 
    print("Error")
```

it skips all my elif statements and just prints an error.

```
def AND_1():
print(A & " AND " & B & " = 0")
AND = 0

def AND_2():
print(A & " AND " & B & " = 0")
AND = 0

def AND_3():
print(A & " AND " & B & " = 0")
AND = 0

def AND_4():
print(A & " AND " & B & " = 1")
AND = 1
```

Comment: `prints an error` - do you mind giving the error?

Comment: indentation is important in python - maybe your code for the def has to move over a bit?

Comment: If there is anything you are unclear of just make sure you leave a message and il wil get back to you.

Comment: yeah sure no problem Patrick

Comment: File "C:/Users/waliu/Desktop/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    first_AND()                                                                                                      
  File "C:/Users/waliu/Desktop/test.py", line 21, in first_AND
    AND_1()
  File "C:/Users/waliu/Desktop/test.py", line 27, in AND_1
    print(A & " AND " & B & " = 0")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: The main problem that wont let the program operate is the fact my If statement arent taking in my inputs of A and B, without the starting line of the program it cant get going

Comment: the main problem is the lack of INDENTATION for your `defs` - python needs it to see what belongs into the `def`. The error states that you misuse the `print()` method  - it does not know what to do with `string & string`. `print(...)` uses `,` to seperate different things you want to print- consult a reference or look at my modified answer where I removed the bugs and added indentation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code for you: you should read up on python syntax, f.e. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/index.html (for 2.7.x) and do some tutorials

```
# define global 
AND = None

#define the used functions
def gate_path_A():
    print("Reached gate_path_A()")
    return


def first_AND (A,B):
    if A == 0 and B == 0: 
        AND_1(A,B)
        print(AND)
        print("Now solve the XOR gate")
        gate_path_A()
    elif A == 1 and B == 0:
        AND_2(A,B)
        print(AND)
        print("Now solve the XOR gate")
        gate_path_A()
    elif A == 0 and B == 1:
        AND_3(A,B)
        print(AND)
        print("Now solve the XOR gate")
        gate_path_A()
    elif A == 1 and B == 1:
        AND_4(A,B)
        print(AND)
        print("Now solve the XOR gate")
        gate_path_A()
    else: 
        print("Error")
    return  


def AND_1(A,B):
    print(A , " AND " , B , " = 0")
    AND = 0
    return

def AND_2(A,B):
    print(A , " AND " , B ," = 0")
    AND = 0
    return

def AND_3(A,B):
    print(A , " AND " , B , " = 0")
    AND = 0
    return

def AND_4(A,B):
    print(A , " AND " , B , " = 1")
    AND = 1
    return
```

**MAIN Program**

```
# get one integer from user
a = None
while a is None:
    try:
        a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an integer value...")
print(str(a));

# get second integer from user 
# you should really put this in a def and return the integer: DRY principle
b = None
while b is None:
    try:
        b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an integer value...")
print(str(b));

# call to the first and thing and supply the params your got from user
first_AND(a,b);
```

Comment: that was what I was thinking to be honest to pass my inputs of A and B as functions. So basically once I write my function I have to to a return statement onto it?

Comment: Here we go this is the problem that I was exactly looking for: NameError: name 'A' is not defined - this is what is the problem and same applies with B. This is what I wrote in my function you suggested Pat.

Comment: def inputs(A, B):
    A = input("Enter a value of 1 or 0: ")
    B = input("Enter a value of 1 or 0: ")
    return A
    return B

Comment: look up how to cretae functions, f.e. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) - you can return smthif you like - or return None.

Comment: Woah thanks patrick Ill test your code here and see if it perfectly works into doing what I intend on it doing an ill have to apply this to the rest of my code based on the XOR gate, carry ouputds of previous gates into our next gates and store results of other gates

Comment: Thank you so much patrick I have tested it and it does what I wanted it to do. I need to study the new sets of code here to make sure I have developed a clear understanding to it

Comment: My past experience with coding was Visual Basic and I know I still have a lot of learning to do with python. But thank you very much Patrick for helping me solve this solution.

Comment: How do I mark a comment in this forum as an answer? Im new to stack overflow. In the past I used MSDN but they dont cover python an MSDN used it for problems on VB

Comment: Lock close to the each answers begining , there should be a tickable field for "mark as answer". If you also upvote an answer I get even more credits (though you cant upvote yet, you need more creds toyour account to enable that feature - click the upvote non the less if you think its ok.)

Comment: I tried it Patrick but it says I am not high levelled enough to mark peoples answers.